# Retrieving JS data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am recording the information using the `data()` method

```
   optionScope.data().stage = 'a';
    where optionScope = $(this);
```

where I would like to store this value in my php code:

```
<?php

  include("functions/db.php");
  $format = "Online Course";
  $stage = GETTING THIS DATA;
  $topic = "Idea Generation";
  $resources = "select * from resources where format LIKE  '".$format."' and stage LIKE '%".$stage."%' ";

  $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $resources);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {


     $stage = $row['stage'];


   echo "$stage  <br>";

 }
 ?>
```

Update:
How the data is being sent

```
optionScope.data().stage = 'b';
  $.ajax({
        url: "functions/contact.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {stage: optionScope.data().stage}
    });
```

How the data is being retrieved

```
<?php

      $stage = $_POST['stage'];
      echo $stage;

?>
```

Comment: How is the php code being run?  AJAX?

Comment: no just regularly. the php code is being included in the main page where the js files are also included

Comment: PHP won't be able to see any of the information from the page it renders unless there's an AJAX call or a form submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly transfer data between JS and PHP (unless you use string interpolation inside `<script>` tags which is a big no-no), since JS deals in the client-side and PHP on the server-side.

You need to make a request to the server and then manipulate the data there.

Take a look at [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests.
For the easiest implementation of this, see [JQuery's AJAX](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/) method.

Comment: `.post()` is actually a shorthand for `.ajax({type: 'POST'})`. It's ajax in both cases.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've applied your suggestion with AJAX. I have made an edit to my post under the update section of my initial post. it doesnt seem to echo out the post

Comment: You need to add a success parameter to your Ajax call to handle what php echo'd.  You should be able to see the that data going back and forth on the network tab of your browser debugger.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the AJAX method. This is the only way you can transfer your JS data into PHP script.you will get the Jquery data in GET or POST variables.
jQuery AJAX has the various method you can choose as per your requirement.
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/